# android ListView touch-animation gone when onClickListener is attached

Tags: android, listview, animation, onclick

I have a ListView with a custom layout for the child items.

Without the OnClickListener attached to the items each item highlights nicely when the user touches it but as soon as I attach the listener the animation is gone. The listener is working but then there is no animation or visual feedback.
The same problem occurs when I use an OnTouchListener.

What can I do to grab the onClick-Event but still have the default animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With ListView you should use OnItemClickListener. If there's is a specific reason for using OnClickListener, you can manually fire the item click event. In your OnClickListener call [performItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.htmll#performItemClick(android.view.View,%20int,%20long)).

Comment: I didn't even see this method. That works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Wow! Thanks you rock it!